# Stochastic Long-Run Mean Instantaneous Variance in Heston Model (and extensions)?

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, stochastic-volatility, european-options

I'm working on my dissertation in Financial Economics, focusing on the topic of Stochastic Volatility Jump Diffusion models; and I'm playing around with some ideas for model extensions. In particular, I am quite interested in the idea of an extension in which the Heston long-run mean instantaneous variance parameter is also stochastic and mean-reverting; i.e. with a (risk-neutral) SDE system of: 
$$dS_{t}=(r_{t}-q_{t}-\lambda \bar{k})S_{t}dt+\sqrt{\nu_{t}}S_{t}dW_{t}^{S}+kS_{t}dN_{t}$$
$$d\nu_{t}=\kappa_{\nu}(\theta_{t}-\nu_{t})dt+\sigma_{\nu}\sqrt{\nu_{t}}dW_{t}^{\nu}$$
$$d\theta_{t}=\kappa_{\theta}(\theta_{\infty}-\theta_{t})dt+\sigma_{\theta}\sqrt{\theta_{t}}dW_{t}^{\theta}$$
$$d\left<W^{S},W^{\nu}\right>=\rho dt$$
$$N_{t}\sim Pois(\lambda t)$$
$$k=\exp(J^{S})-1$$
$$\bar{k}=\mathbb{E}^{Q}\left[k\right],$$

such that $\theta_{\infty}$, $\kappa_{\theta}$, $\sigma_{\theta}$ are the analogous paramaters of the long-run mean instantaneous variance DE to those of the DE for the spot instantaneous variance $\nu_{t}$. I leave open the questions of the jump size distribution (from which the general solution approach is independent assuming independent jumps) as to whether or not the long-run mean instantaneous variance is correlated with any of the other parameters in the model. (I see no reason why it should have to be.)

My question to you guys: is anyone aware of any literature that deals with such a model specification, either with or without jumps included? I ask because I have tried deriving the European Option price Heston/Bates style that would require a $\theta_{t}$ coefficient in the Characteristic Function, and I end up with a rather nasty Riccati DE for that coefficient that is stretching me beyond the limit of my talent I fear. (Or which may simply have no closed-form solution.)

Alternatively, if any of you are feeling lucky today and would like to help a simple mind like my mine try to derive a solution, that would also be greatly appreciated; let me know, I'll type out the DE for you to take a stab at.

Comment: The approach of modelling the long-term mean level of the variance process as stochastic is quite common. One of the earliest references that I am aware of is http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/jgatheral/Bachelier2008.pdf - see the slide titled "double CEV dynamics".

Comment: Hi Local Volatility, my apologies for the late response. Thank you so much for the link! It was really helpful.